# Speed up wkhtmltopdf in Laravel to print thousands of pages

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, supervisord

I am using *Laravel 8* and *wkhtmltopdf* to convert dynamically generated HTML to PDF files. The problem is that the process is too slow. Each job is split into at least 20 chunks, and each chunk is a job in a batch that then gets queued according to [these instructions](https://divinglaravel.com/queue-job-batching-in-laravel-how-it-works). Using *supervisord*, I am spawning 20 PHP processes. When I run the document generator, all 20 PHP processes get to work, and they launch 20 *wkhtmltopdf* processes. Everything is happening in the same docker container.

Increasing resources from 1 CPU and 1GB RAM to 2 CPUs and 4GB of RAM nearly doubled the speed. Sadly, going from that to 4 CPUs and 8GB of RAM has not brought any measurable speed gain.

Current speed is 4 files per second. I have tens of thousands to process. Where can I get more performance? What can I change without adding more hardware resources?

Comment: If increasing CPU and/or memory no longer increases the performance, maybe try adding additional machines? One machine spec’d at 4/sec should scale horizontally, I’d think.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I have been thinking about that, but I am hesitating because that may mean rewriting the code so it works with several containers

Comment: "Everything is happening in the same docker container" - why not use additional physical machines?

Comment: Is this something that will run forever, or do you just need to convert a bunch of documents and once done, 4/sec will be an acceptable going forward?

Comment: Yes it's a system that should churn out millions of PDF files per month for a few years

Comment: I’d just bite the bullet and refactor. Have a central queue, could be a real one, or just a simple database. Have your worker process “checkout” batches. That should be relatively easy to build and throw workers at. You could also tweak the PDF generation settings, maybe, but we’d need to see that specific code. I’d also get a profiler like Blackfire to inspect how the resources are used, and if there’s any hidden issues.

Comment: I guess you are right @ChrisHaas
Let me get to work. While I'm at it, I may also try mPDF